# "exempt" usage: adjective or verb

Tags: verbs, word-form, adjectives

> Children are **exempt** from the charges.
>
> Children are **exempted** from the charges.

From these two sentences, the former is an example Longman dictionary provides for the word "exempt". My question is that whether the latter, which replaces the adjective **exempt** with the verb **exempted**, would be grammatically acceptable as well? And if it would, does that replacement induce any discrepancy in terms of meaning or connotation?

Comment: This happens with lots of verbs. The children could be *free/freed* from hunger, *subject/subjected* to random strip-searches, for example. Using the "verb" form may slightly call more attention to the fact that somebody or something must be *doing* the "verbing", but it's not really a significant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same thing, but the second one calls attention to the fact that the exemption came from somewhere or someone.

Imagine you're talking to some bureaucrat at a counter. She smiles at your children, passes your money back, and says "You don't need to pay this; children are exempt."

Different situation. You don't have enough money, and children are *not* normally exempt. "Okay, we'll make an exception." She scribbles her name on a piece of paper and writes "Children are exempted from the charges by my authority."

You could still used exempted in the first case, but you *cannot* use exempt in the second one.

Comment: I don't agree that you *cannot* use exempt in the second example. That's only true if you parse it as equivalent to *My authority exempts the children*, not if you parse it as *By my authority [this statement is true]*.

Comment: In that case, though, don't you read it as "all children are exempt" not just this batch?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think GH meant we cannot use "exempt" in the second sentence without rephrasing (while we can use "exempted" in the first sentence - still without being have to rephrase).

Comment: Greg, I personally can't see any reason to assume the potential scope of "children" is affected by that aspect of the phrasing. @Nate: My first comment meant exactly what it said - so far as I'm concerned there's nothing wrong with *"Children are **exempt** from the charges by my authority"*, and it means exactly the same as the same utterance with the explicitly verbal form ***exempted***.

Comment: Then, as often with language, I think we just have a difference of opinion. I do read a difference unless, as Nate suggests, the sentences are rephrased.